# IIS 6 - cant authenticate from localhost but can from other locations

Tags: iis, active-directory, authentication

I have a windows 2003 server on an AD domain that hosts an IIS 6 website (currently using http, no SSL).

When set to basic auth I can log in as an AD user from both the local system (IE8) and remote PCs (Various).

When set to Integrated Windows auth we can log in from remote systems fine, but trying to log in by running IE on the server itself fails; it rejects the password 3 times then gives a permission denied error.  We've tried multiple host names, and we've tried editing the hosts file to connect to both 127.0.0.1 and 10.1.1.1 (the servers  IP)

What could be causing IE on the web server to fail while external browsers are fine?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a look at the System event log on the Web Server. I would look for anything in the relevant time frame that is a warning or error and in particular I would look for events with a source of W3SVC, ASP.NET, W32Time or Kerberos.

Are you using Kerberos?

Another useful measure is to examine the HTTP traffic. A tool like Firebug or fiddler may make the problem obvious.

Can you login with Firefox? http://digg.com/story/r/How_To_Firefox_and_Integrated_Windows_Authentication

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/208599/cannot-log-in-to-windows-auth-protected-pages-while-on-the-server/210579#210579 It is probably the loopbackcheck "feature".